# Comando PRINT consta como INVALID SYNTAX em Python

Tags: python, syntax-error

Estou fazendo um exercício simples em python e não entendi o motivo do meu erro.

```
num1 = (int(input("Digite o primeiro número"))
print("Digite a operação desejada, sendo:")
print("* --> MULTIPLICAÇÃO")
print("/ --> DIVISÃO")
print("+ --> SOMA")
op = input("- --> SUBTRAÇÃO")
num2 = (int(input("Digite o segundo número"))
```

O erro está na linha `print("Digite a operação desejada, sendo:")` e diz `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
Agradeço quem puder me ajudar!

Comment: Tem um parênteses a mais na primeira linha. Retire o `(` antes de `int` - o mesmo vale para a última linha

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> "File "", line 2
> print("Digite a operação desejada, sendo:")
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

o Erro está na primeira linha: **num1 = (int(input("Digite o primeiro número"))**

O correto seria: **num1 = int(input("Digite o primeiro número: "))**

Código completo:

```
num1 = int(input("Digite o primeiro número: "))
print("Digite a operação desejada, sendo:")
print("* --> MULTIPLICAÇÃO")
print("/ --> DIVISÃO")
print("+ --> SOMA")
op = input("- --> SUBTRAÇÃO")
num2 = int(input("Digite o primeiro número: "))
```